# Creating 1 decimal place

Tags: java, while-loop, decimal

So I am more or less completely done with this code that runs a guessing game. At the end it prints the total results for all games played. This includes total games, total guesses, avg guesses/game and the best score. I have it all worked out except i need the avg guesses/game to show 1 decimal place but the `System.out.printf("Guesses/game = %.1f")` isn't working and idk why

```
import java.util.*; //so I can use scanner

public class GuessingGame {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

      Random rand = new Random ();
      int max = 100;
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      int guess;
      boolean play = true;
      int totalGames = 0;
      int totalGuesses = 0;
      int bestGame = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

      System.out.println("Can you guess the word?");
      System.out.println("I am sure you cannot guess!");
      System.out.println("Go ahead and try!");
      System.out.println();

      while (play) { //repeats until user enters a statement besides y when asked to play again

         System.out.println("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and " + max + "...");
         int numberToGuess = rand.nextInt(max) + 1;
         int numberOfTries = 0;
         boolean win = false;
         while (!win) {

            System.out.print("Your guess? ");
            guess = input.nextInt();
            numberOfTries++;

            if (guess == numberToGuess) {
               win = true;  
            } else if (guess > numberToGuess) {
               System.out.println("It's lower.");
            } else if (guess < numberToGuess) {
               System.out.println("It's higher.");
            }      
            input.nextLine();
         }
         if (numberOfTries == 1) {
            System.out.println("You got it right in " + numberOfTries + " guess!");
         } else {
            System.out.println("You got it right in " + numberOfTries + " guesses!");
         }   
            totalGames++;
            totalGuesses+= numberOfTries;
            System.out.print("Do you want to play again? ");

            String answer = input.nextLine();
            char firstLetter = answer.charAt(0);
            if (firstLetter == 'y' || firstLetter == 'Y') {
            play = true;  
            } else {
            play = false;     
            bestGame = Math.min(bestGame, numberOfTries);             
         }  
         System.out.println();            
      }

      System.out.println("Overall results:");
      System.out.println("Total games = " + totalGames);  
      System.out.println("Total guesses = " +  totalGuesses);
      System.out.printf("Guesses/game = ", totalGuesses/totalGames);
      System.out.println("Best game = " + bestGame);
   }  
}
```

Comment: Java is not Javascript

Comment: Please explain what "isn't working" means: won't compile?  Prints the wrong thing (if so, what, and what should it be?).

Comment: it compiles just fine i get an error message that says:

`Guesses/game = Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f != java.lang.Integer
 at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:4302)
 at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printFloat(Formatter.java:2806)
 at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:2753)
 at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2520)
 at java.io.PrintStream.format(PrintStream.java:970)
 at java.io.PrintStream.printf(PrintStream.java:871)
 at GuessingGame.main(GuessingGame.java:64)`

Comment: @Dici sorry I'm still pretty new

Answer (score 1):

both totalGuesses and totalGames are integers, so when you divide them you get an integer, whereas %f needs a floating point number.

Instead cast one to a floating point number for floating point division:

```
totalGuesses/(double)totalGames
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a decimal formatter if for some reason you're simply getting the wrong output:

```
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
System.out.println(formatter.format(avgGuesses)); //or whatever your var name is
```